# Set the width of image equal to an item width in the enumerated list

Tags: vertical-alignment, lists, enumerate

I have an enumerated list in which I am inserting an image using `\linewidth`, but it is taking the full space as taken by `\textwidth`. My output is looking as

[image]

My code is as follows

```
  \begin{enumerate}

          \item QoS 0: blah blah blah!

          \item QoS 1: blah blah blah!

          \item QoS 2: blah blah blah!

          \begin{figure}[!h]
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{images/chap2/qos_consolidated} 
          \caption{Various QoS types }
          \label{fig:qos_consolidated}
          \end{figure}

        \end{enumerate}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the image is not in the list, it is in a `figure` . The _only_ reason to use a `figure` environment is to mark the content as not being part of the main text flow but to be an insert that can be moved so the current settings are not used. just use `\begin{center}\includegraphics{...}\end{center}` if you want the image to be in the list.

Comment: It worked, Thanks a lot . You can provide it as an answer.  The only issue I have now is to put a caption on this figure. I got the error `Package caption Error: \caption outside float \caption`

Comment: You don't need a caption  on non floating images but if you want one use `capt-of` or `caption` package and `\captionof{figure}[zzzz}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is not in the list, it is in a figure . The only reason to use a figure environment is to mark the content as not being part of the main text flow but to be an insert that can be moved so the current settings are not used.

Just use

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{...}
\end{center}
```

if you want the image to be in the list.

You don't need a caption  on non floating images but if you want one use `capt-of` or `caption` package and `\captionof{figure}{zzzz}`